# RewriteRule for first directory in URL only

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure how to phrase this RewriteRule without also redirecting all requests for .css and .js files.

I need

> domain.com/randomfolder/

to go to my domain's index(ie. domain.com/index.php) for whatever folder is requested but keep the url intact.

It seems easy enough but I can't seem to specify that I only want the first instance of a directory to redirect.

For example:

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

works to redirect, but when my index.php calls for /css/main.css it returns the index.php.

Is there a way to say that **domain.com/subdirectory/** should redirect but **domain.com/subdirectory/file.css** should not?

I'm okay with just excluding /css/ and /js/ directories but I don't know how.

Comment: So we need to get to the bottom of what you really want.  Are you trying to redirect requests that are not to actual files and/or folders in the directory structure to index.php?  That is a typical way that a front controller such as this would be implemented.  If not are you truly wanting to redirect everything except requests to *.css and *.js files?  What about images (if any)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?folder=$1 [L]
```

This will redirect `www.example.com/subdirectory/` to `www.example.com/index.php?folder=subdirectory` without altering the URL that the visitor sees. It won't redirect requests for any specific file in a subdirectory, nor will it redirect requests for a subdirectory within a subdirectory.

```
URL Requested:                Redirect:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
example.com/css               example.com/index.php?folder=css
example.com/css/              example.com/index.php?folder=css
example.com/css/main.css      example.com/css/main.css (no redirect)
example.com/css/js/           example.com/css/js/      (no redirect)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add an extra slash to the stylesheet href before it would work. (href="css/main.css" > href="/css/main.css")

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<Files ~ "\.(css|js)$">
    RewriteRule ^subdirectory(.*)$ index.php
</Files>
```